# Famous Finite Sets

Tags: big-list, recreational-mathematics, examples-counterexamples

What are the most famous (or most beautiful, IYO) *finite* sets in mathematics? I'm especially looking for 'large' sets that contain more than $2^{10} \approx 1000$ but fewer than $2^{20} \approx 1{,}000{,}000$ elements.

I'll start the ball rolling with the five [platonic solids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid). (Unfortunately not large.)

Comment: 6 775 235 700 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population) is a bit bigger then 2^20, but still it is a finite set of such cardinality where all of us are elements.

Comment: @Gortaur: "in mathematics."

Comment: I can't wait until Asaf sees this question...

Comment: I wonder if the set of [reducible configurations in the first computer-assisted proof of four-color theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#Proof_by_computer) count. There were apparently 1936 of them. :)

Comment: I don't understand the motivation behind this question.

Comment: I think a good place to start would be the OEIS entries that have the "fini" keyword: http://oeis.org/search?q=keyword:fini

Comment: This is not actually a question in the sense of this site.  It is a call for a discussion, or referendum, on people's tastes and preferences.  I have voted to close.

Answer (score 7):

As is well known, every finite (natural) number can be associated with a finite set of that cardinality. So in particular, the cardinality of a famous or special finite set must be a famous or special number. [Here's a list of all the special numbers less than or equal to 9999](https://erich-friedman.github.io/numbers.html) and contains quite a few items between $2^{10}$ and $2^{20}$.

Oh, what, you actually want the sets, and not just their cardinality, because there is more than one way of realising a set of a given cardinality? (Me grumbles something about bijective maps and isomorphisms of sets.) Fine:

- 1132 is the number of 3-valent trees with 15 vertices
- 1144 is the number of non-invertible knots with 12 crossings.
- 1165 is the number of conjugacy classes in the automorphism group of the 12 dimensional hypercube.
- 1205 is the number of fullerenes with 58 carbon atoms
- 1294 is the number of 4 dimensional polytopes with 8 vertices.
- 1378 is the number of symmetric idempotent 6×6 matrices over GF(2).
- 1411 is the number of quasi-groups of order 5.
- ...
- 3240 is the number of 3×3×3 Rubik's cube positions that require exactly 3 moves to solve.
- 3286 is the number of stable patterns with 16 cells in Conway's game of Life.
- ...
- 4535 is the number of unlabeled topologies with 7 elements.
- ...

As beauty is in the eye of the beholder, I'm sure there are mathematicians out there who think each of the above numbers *ought* to be better known.

Answer (score 5):

The sporadic groups? In particular they are finite sets... quite a few are too big to fit into your range, but the smallest (Mathieu groups) would do the trick.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporadic_groups